# What is this operator in "The Temporal Logic of Programs" Pnueli 1977?

Tags: linear-temporal-logic, program-correctness

In [The Temporal Logic of Programs](http://fi.ort.edu.uy/innovaportal/file/20124/1/49-pnueli_temporal_logic_of_programs.pdf) there is an operator first appearing on page 3 (48) under "Partial Correctness" that looks like an elongated super set symbol. What is it?

Comment: Based on context it seems like it could mean implication, which is supported by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's implication as indicated in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols